# What is the 'repair code' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

OK I was adding an index to a table, and I checked on progress using `show processlist` and under `state` it output `Repair by sorting`.

From the MySQL docs:

> Repair by sorting
>
> The repair code is using a sort to create indexes.

So what is the 'repair code'? Did something break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing broke, it's just part of the process of rebuilding indexes on a table. This can take quite a while on very large tables.

Comment: +1 !!! This also includes the dreaded 'Repair by keycache' if sort buffers are not large enough for 'Repair by sorting' to complete.